# Web api giving 426 upgrade required message while calling from android studio

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, okhttp, tls1.2

Web api giving 426 upgrade required message while calling from android studio[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWIBs.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is expecting the request to be HTTP/1.1 or higher. Upgrade to the right version of the protocol in your client.